# Automatically assign color to nodes in Graphviz

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, graphviz

I'm using Python and Graphviz to draw some cluster graph consist of nodes.
I want to assign different colors to each node, dependent on an attribute, e.g.  its x-coordinate.

Here's how I produce graph:

```
def add_nodes(graph, nodes):
    for n in nodes:
        if isinstance(n, tuple):
            graph.node(n[0], **n[1])
        else:
            graph.node(n)
    return graph

A = [[517, 1, [409], 10, 6], 
     [534, 1, [584], 10, 12], 
     [614, 1, [247], 11, 5], 
     [679, 1, [228], 13, 7], 
     [778, 1, [13], 14, 14]]

nodesgv = []

for node in A:
    nodesgv.append((str(node[0]),{'label': str(node[0]), 'color': ???, 'style': 'filled'}))

graph = functools.partial(gv.Graph, format='svg', engine='neato')
add_nodes(graph(), nodesgv).render(('img/test'))
```

And now I want to assign a color to each node with the ordering of the first value of each node.
More specifically what I want is:

- a red node (517)
- a yellow node (534)
- a green node (614)
- a blue node (679)
- and a purple node (778)

[image: 5 differently coloured nodes with numbers in them: red, yellow, green, blue, purple. 517, 534, 614, 679, 778]

I know how to assign colors to the graph, but what I'm looking for is something similar to the c=x part when using matplotlib.

Problem is I'm not able to know the number of nodes (clusters) beforehand, so for example if I've got 7 nodes, I still want a graph with 7 nodes that start from a red one, and end with a purple one.

```
plt.scatter(x, y, c=x, s=node_sizes)
```

So is there any attribute in Graphviz that can do this?

Or can anyone tell me how does the colormap in matplotlib work?

Sorry for the lack of clarity. T^T

Comment: You can always use capture the return from grahpviz and then call `set_array`, `set_norm`, `set_cmap` etc on it.

Comment: How you produce your graph? Do you look just for color assignment to a node or for sequence of color assignment?

Comment: @Ohad Eytan I edited the article. Sry for been unclear

Comment: Your question is how to get the matplotlib colors specifically or just how to assign colors to the graph?

Comment: I know how to assign colors to the graph, but what I'm looking for is something similar to the c=x part when using matplotlib.
Problem is I'm not able to know the number of nodes(clusters) beforehand, so for example if I got 7 nodes, I still want a graph with 7 nodes start from a red one and end with a purple one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh I figured out a way to get what I want.
Just for recording and for someone else may have a same problem(?)
Can just rescale a color map and assign the corresponding index (of color) to the nodes.

```
def add_nodes(graph, nodes):
for n in nodes:
    if isinstance(n, tuple):
        graph.node(n[0], **n[1])
    else:
        graph.node(n)
return graph

A = [[517, 1, [409], 10, 6], 
     [534, 1, [584], 10, 12], 
     [614, 1, [247], 11, 5], 
     [679, 1, [228], 13, 7], 
     [778, 1, [13], 14, 14]]

nodesgv = []
Arange = [ a[0] for a in A]
norm = mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin = min(Arange), vmax = max(Arange))
cmap = cm.jet

for index, i in enumerate(A):
    x = i[0]
    m = cm.ScalarMappable(norm = norm, cmap = cmap)
    mm = m.to_rgba(x)
    M = colorsys.rgb_to_hsv(mm[0], mm[1], mm[2])
    nodesgv.append((str(i[0]),{'label': str((i[1])), 'color': "%f, %f, %f" % (M[0], M[1], M[2]), 'style': 'filled'}))

graph = functools.partial(gv.Graph, format='svg', engine='neato')
add_nodes(graph(), nodesgv).render(('img/test'))
```