# Graphviz: give color to lines with rainbow effect

Tags: python, pandas, graphviz

I have dataframe and I build graph using `graphviz`

```
for id_key, group in df.groupby('ID'):
f = Digraph('finite_state_machine', filename='fsm.gv', encoding='utf-8')
f.body.extend(['rankdir=LR', 'size="5,5"'])
f.attr('node', shape='box')
for i in range(len(group)-1):
    f.edge(str(group['category'].iloc[i]), str(group['category'].iloc[i+1]),
           label=str(group['search_term'].iloc[i+1]))
f.render(filename=str(id_key))
```

and get this result 
[image]. How can I change lines color: first arrow - red, second - orange, third - yellow, etc?

Answer (score 6):

You can use one of the [brewer color schemes](http://graphviz.org/doc/info/colors.html#brewer). For example:

```
g = graphviz.Digraph(format='png')
g.body.extend(["rankdir=LR"])
for i in range(9):
    g.edge(str(i),str(i+1),color="/spectral9/"+str(i+1))
g.render(filename="example")
```

produce:

[image: example]

If you wish to generate the colors yourself you can use the [hsv format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) with constants *saturation* & *value* and increasing *hue*:

```
n = 20
g = graphviz.Digraph(format='png')
g.body.extend(["layout=circo"])
for i in range(n):
    g.edge(str(i),str(i+1),color="{h:} 1 1".format(h=i/n))
g.edge(str(n),str(0),color="1 1 1")
g.render(filename="example")
```

produce:

[image: example2]

Comment: if I use iloc, how can I rewrite that?

Comment: I get this `Warning: /spectral9/11 is not a known color.`

Comment: there are not a lot of colors and after color it prints black

Comment: You can use `spectral11` which gives you two more colors. If you want more you can generate the colors yourself.

Comment: If I use `spectral13` a get all arrows black

Comment: As you can see in the link I provided `spectral11` is the largest scheme.

Comment: But how can I generate more colors?

Comment: I am writing from my phone, but you can see similar example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38909236/2069380)

Comment: but it's number of color, but I need more colors in spectr

Comment: what is `n`? What I should specify instead that?

Comment: number of nodes/edges

Comment: Can you say, I use your code `n=30
for id_key, group in df.groupby('ID'):
    f = Digraph('finite_state_machine', filename='fsm.gv', encoding='utf-8')
    f.body.extend(['rankdir=LR', 'size="5,5"'])
    f.attr('node', shape='box')
    for i in range(len(group)-1):
        f.edge(str(group['category'].iloc[i]), str(group['category'].iloc[i + 1]),
                label=str(group['search_term'].iloc[i + 1]), color="{h:} 1 1".format(h=i/n), penwidth='3')
    f.render(filename=str(id_key))` but it return me only red arrows. Why?

Comment: I run ypur code without my data and there are only red color

Comment: I have no idea why. Maybe you can try and add commas: `colors="{:h}, 1.0, 1.0"`

Comment: it's strange. nothing changed

Comment: You can see in the picture what I got

Comment: Why I have another result, I don't understand

Comment: what version of graphviz do you use?

Comment: My package version is `0.4.8.dev0`

Comment: Nice! This looks so beautiful!